# Как получить массив из объекта?

Tags: php

Есть API, которое дает мне объект, который я преобразовываю в массив:

```
$posSummary = (array)$pageOfpositionsSummary;
```

Получается результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно взять содержимое блока [*result] и поместить в свой массив, для этого я использую такую конструкцию:

```
$google_stat = self::getStatPosition($topvisor_id, 1, $region); 
$posStat['google'] = $google_stat;
```

Пробовал так:

```
$site = systems::$db->select('site', ['region', 'topvisor_id'], ['id' => $site_id])[0];
        $posStat = array();
        if (isset($site['topvisor_id'])) {
            $region = $site['region'];
            $topvisor_id = $site['topvisor_id'];
            $yandex_stat = self::getStatPosition($topvisor_id, 0, $region);
            print_r($yandex_stat);
            foreach ($yandex_stat as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
                    if ($key2 == 'dates') {
                        $posStat['yandex']['dates'] = $value2;
                    }
                    if ($key2 == 'tops') {
                        $posStat['yandex']['tops'] = $value2;
                    }
                }
            }
            print_r($posStat); // - ХРЕН ТЕБЕ
            $google_stat = self::getStatPosition($topvisor_id, 1, $region);
            $posStat['google'] = $google_stat;
            // print_r($posStat);
```

В итоге ошибка о том, что нельзя обращаться к `result`. При этом при `foreach` и выводе ключей, ключ выводится, а при обращении сообщение, что его нет.

Comment: $posSummary = (array)$pageOfpositionsSummary->{'*result'};

Comment: Спасибо, у API есть функция оказывается getResult() - а при такой обращении она ругается так как объект защищен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для более удобной работы переформатируйте полученные данные из `stdClass` в `array`.

[Как это сделать.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php)
А после просто возьмите нужную информацию по ключам массива.